# Может ли пользователь сайта изменить переменные в js?

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Решил попробовать написать браузерную онлайн игру для практики в программировании и появляются вопросы.
может ли пользователь сайта изменить переменные в js (Я передаю переменные через ajax)?

И какие советы по улучшению безопасности для игры? (Игра на PHP, js)

Comment: Всегда проверять входящие данные и не доверять юзеру, а лучше делать так что бы данные всегда были исходящими

Answer (score 3):

Стоит рассуждать так: всё что работает на стороне клиента  - всё можно подделать. JS, HTML - клиент, PHP - сервер. Старайтесь сделать так, чтобы всё, что не стоит редактировать пользователям работало на сервере. К примеру: покупка на рынке меча: AJAX запрос на сервер  buyItem и уже там на PHP написать чтобы в инвентарь падала вещь, а со счёта списывались деньги. Или передвижение. К примеру в игре есть карта, по  которой можно ходить. Соответственно сама анимация движения должна быть на JS, но на сервер должна отсылаться координата, и там же проверять если координата слишком резко изменилась (пользователь попытался "телепортироваться") то значит попытка взлома. В общем в эту сторону думаете. Зависит от того, какая игра у Вас)

Comment: @iproger то есть в data написать buyItem?

Comment: @lordvakar, ну у Вас должен быть PHP обработчик запросов. Допустим самое простое на файл ajax.php посылать аяксом POST запрос с data="handler=buyItem&itemId=32"

Comment: @iproger я уже думал об этом, спасибо большое :)

Answer (score 1):

Редактировать на лету JS - можно.
Варианты безопасности, хотелось бы знать что вы там собираетесь хранить, вообще кодирование как вариант, а еще лучше все необходимые данные хранить в БД, а выводить только то что нужно.

Comment: @Manitikyl данные и так будут храниться в БД.
Как мне тогда выполнить определённые действия в PHP, просто послав запрос через ajax, без каких либо переменных? 
У меня много ещё вопросов, было бы не плохо получить ответ, но тут комментарии не позволяют разгуляться.

Comment: @lordvakar , как-как?
Создаешь определенные методы, с определенным набором функций, и вызываешь - из исходящих данных останется только запрос к методу. 
Проверять что либо можно из сессии или куков.

Comment: @lordvakar, ну пишите в скайп Manitikyl. поговорим)))

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых никогда не доверять пользователю и проверять все введенные данные. Это и данные введенные из форм, так и данные полученные через ajax.

Во-вторых использовать токен для подтверждения пользователя.

Теперь со стороны client-side. В третьих использовать паттерн модуль и всю логики поместить в него и не пользоваться глобальным пространством имен, тогда на js-код никак нельзя будет повлиять.

В-четвертых использовать минификацию, которая заменит все имена переменных, произвольные и понять код будет очень сложно.

В-пятых если боитесь что пользователь поймет что передаете через Ajax, то для сокрытия можно использовать какую нибудь простую защиту типа: все числа умножать на 17, а string сдвигать влево на 3 символа и пропускать через Base64. Защита слабая, но сбить с толку поможет.

Comment: > третьих использовать паттерн модуль и всю логики поместить в него и не пользоваться глобальным пространством имен, тогда на js-код никак нельзя будет повлиять. 

break point в дебагере  как минимум

> В-четвертых использовать минификацию, которая заменит все имена переменных, произвольные и понять код будет очень сложно. 

сейчас вроде-бы все дебагеры позволяют отформатировать минифицированный код и обычно в нем не сложно разобраться

5й способ припарка.

Comment: Все верно, всегда остаются способы воздействовать на JS код. Можно лишь усложнить задачу вмешаться в клиентский код. Именно поэтому логику необходимо располагать на стороне сервера. А какие то важные действия только там.